# How to automaticaly remove folders and its content, which are more than 20 days old?

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, cron, rm

I have a parent folder `raw_response_csvfiles` which contains multiple folders named `a,b,c...z`.

`a,b,c...z` folders contain lot of `csv` files.

How do I automatically remove the folders `a,b,c..z` and the `csv` files inside it, which are more than 30 days old ?

I am looking for a bash script that I can put as a `cron` job.

I came up with this, but it only removes the `csv` files and not the folders `a,b,c....z`:

```
*/5 * * * *  /usr/bin/find "raw_response_csvfiles" -name \*.csv -mtime +20 -delete
```

Comment: Drop the `-name` parameter?

Comment: wont that delete **raw_response_csvfiles** ?..I want to delete folders inside it

Comment: Test the command before using Cron to start it.

Comment: Droping the `-name` parameter is not working

Comment: `-mindepth 1` to avoid deleting parent

Answer (score 1):

```
*/5 * * * *  /usr/bin/find /somepath/raw_response_csvfiles/ -type f -name "*.csv" -mtime +20 -exec /usr/bin/rm -f {} \;
```

will just work in a cron environnement for the files

if you also want to destroy directories a,b,c..z
you might build a dedicated line of cron for them with executing a `rm -rf {}` in the exec part.

Or if you want to destroy all them on on shot :

```
*/5 * * * *  /usr/bin/find /somepath/raw_response_csvfiles/ -name "[a-z]" -type d -mtime +20 -exec /usr/bin/rm -rf {} \;
```

Other point using `*/5` for finding files or directory is a very bad approach... what is your real need behind managing those files is the question you have to think about to avoid doing crapped  procedures like that

Comment: i don't get the point of using `rm` for `-delete`

Comment: rm has many command line options/parameters ; I don't think delete have .

Comment: there is absolutely no reason for spawning new child process for each `-exec \;` (instead `-delete`, or `-exec +` at least)